# Cannot access my system after setting a Grub password

Tags: password, grub-legacy

Since I realised that GRUB is not password protected, I have been slightly concerned, as any can get access to my system configuration. I decided to act on it, and followed the instructions in this answer:[How to add the GRUB password protection to the OS load process instead of when editing boot options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370693/how-to-add-the-grub-password-protection-to-the-os-load-process-instead-of-when-e)

I rebooted, and the GRUB screen showed. I booted into Ubuntu, and was prompted for a username. I entered the credentials (username:root, password: the one I set in the make password command). It simply took me back to the GRUB menu. I thought I entered it wrong so I reentered them. Still no luck. I am now locked out of my system. I am very sure that my password is correct. Is there any way to resolve this situation?

(Note: **I am using GRUB, not Grub2**, and modified the commands as such)

UPDATE: I have a Windows 10 partition on my machine. I now realize that it was still possible to access system configuration by pressing the F2, F11 and F12 keys. I have booted into the Windows 10 partition by changing the boot order. Is there any way to access and rescue my Ubuntu partition from there? Please answer as soon as possible.
(How can I recover my files using LiveCD?)

Comment: You can regain your important things via live CD. Just noting this option.

Comment: Or by plugging the HDD into another Linux box.