# Make usb read-only in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, usb, read-only

I have an USB device. I want share my document to Windows people using it but don't want they change anything inside USB. I think it like read-only. How can I do that?
Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Security Philosophy:

**One who has physical access to the device, IS THE OWNER of the device, no matter what.**

So what you want cannot be achieved in an absolute sense. Users could copy all your files with the read access, format the drive and gain full access, put in whatever they want and give it back to you!

You could format the drive as read only, then the drive would be read only for you as well.

See this thread for very interesting insights

https://www.techrepublic.com/forums/discussions/how-to-add-write-protection-to-flash-drives/

You'll also love to read this answer

https://askubuntu.com/a/842077

Comment: @HữuTuấnAnh You are welcome :)